# How to observe the value of an NSTextField

Tags: key-value-observing, nstextfield

This might seem straightforward, but the following code does not work, because the "observeValueForKeyPath" function is never called, although I keep changing the text in the NSTextfield:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [myNSTextField addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"value" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:nil];
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    NSLog(@"observeValueForKeyPath");
}
```

The log message @"observeValueForKeyPath" is never printed. I tried observing the key @"stringValue", but this does not work neither...

Am I missing something ??

Answer (score 1):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(textFieldDIdChange:) 
                                             name:NSControlTextDidChangeNotification 
                                           object:self.textField];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:NSTextViewDidChangeSelectionNotification
            object:self.textView 
            queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] 
            usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note){
                NSLog(@"Text: %@", self.textView.textStorage.string);
            }];
```

Comment: This code is for an `NSTextView`, not an `NSTextField`. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11488611/39974) suggests setting a delegate that implements the `NSTextFieldDelegate` protocol and implementing the `controlTextDidChange:` delegate method.