# How to capture user input in real time in NSTextField?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextfield

I can capture string when user click the button.
and I also use the following method

```
- (BOOL)control:(NSControl *)control textShouldBeginEditing:(NSText *)fieldEditor
```

which declared in NSControlTextEditingDelegate Protocol.
And when user begin editing, the button will be available.

**My Question is:**
How to make the button disable when user delete all text (make the textField empty without clicking button)?

The above method seems can not do it...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Text change notification for an NSTextField](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487443/text-change-notification-for-an-nstextfield)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at using the `NSControlTextDidChangeNotification` or `controlTextDidChange:` delegate method (from `NSControl`) which is posted by the text field. When you receive the callback you can examine the text currently in the field to decide what to do.

Answer (score 2):

If your `NSText` is a `NSTextView` you may also use [NSTextDelegate Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTextDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) and [NSTextViewDelegate Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Reference/NSTextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

Among others, the `NSTextDelegate` Protocol declares this delegate method:

> `textDidChange:`
>
> Informs the delegate that the text object has changed its characters or formatting attributes.
>
> `- (void)textDidChange:(NSNotification *)aNotification`
>
> **Discussion**
>
> The name of aNotification is NSTextDidChangeNotification.

The `NSTextDidChangeNotification` is documented here [NSTextDidChangeNotification](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSText_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/data/NSTextDidChangeNotification)

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to do the same thing.  This version lets you easily catch specific keystrokes of interest.

```
- (BOOL)textView:(NSTextView *)aTextView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)affectedCharRange replacementString:(NSString *)replacementString{
     NSLog(@"last character entered: %@",replacementString);
}
```

for instance, if you were looking for the return key, you might then implement:

```
if ([replacementString characterAtIndex:0] == NSNewlineCharacter)
    NSLog(@"return pressed");
```

Comment: This is for NSTextView. Not NSTextField.