# os x nstextfield validation

Tags: swift, macos

I have a variable in my `NSViewController`:

```
dynamic var roll_rate:Double = 0.0
```

I attach it to my `NSTextField`:

[image]

Model Key Path shows error, but it is working: When i changed value in field, variable changed too. But what means:
`Validates Immediately` and how do i show and check validation errors for field.

I tried implement method `validateRoll_rate`, but it didn't call when value changed.

Comment: @JoshuaNozzi i tried implement it in my NSViewController

Comment: @JoshuaNozzi but i don't understand what arguments i need... is there some example on swift

Comment: @JoshuaNozzi i don't have code, i did all via UI. And show screenshot in question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Generic solution (work with or without bindings)** One way of dealing with this is based on the response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487443/text-change-notification-for-an-nstextfield)

Basically you use the `controlTextDidChange(notification:)` delegate method of `NSTextField` and you implement your validation code in it.

```
 override func controlTextDidChange (notification: NSNotification) {
    guard let textField = notification.object as? NSTextField else { return }

    // test here, replace the dummy test below with something useful
    if textField.stringValue != "expected value" {
        myTextFieldOutlet.backgroundColor = NSColor.red
        myErrorLabelOutlet.stringValue = "Error !!!"
    } else {
        // everything OK, reset the background color and error label to the normal state
        ....
    }
 }
```

Obviously `myTextFieldOutlet` is an outlet linked to your text field and `myErrorLabelOutlet` is an outlet to a conveniently placed label used to show errors (blank if no error should be presented)

**Bindings oriented solution** Be sure `Validates immediately` is selected in Interface Builder and implement the following method in the class where the binding is made (`Tuning View Controller` in your example)

```
override func validateValue(_ ioValue: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<AnyObject?>, forKey inKey: String) throws {
    // test here, replace the dummy test below with something useful
    if roll_rate > 10.0 {
        throw NSError(domain: "your-domain", code: 100, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Error, roll rate too high"])
    }
}
```

When the error is thrown, the user will be presented with the standard sheet announcing the error and the option to cancel the change or correct it.

If `Continuously updates value` is selected in Interface Builder the method above will be called for each keystroke in the text field, otherwise only after pressing `Enter` or loosing focus.

Note: For a full understanding on how updating values through bindings work, including what `Validates immediately` does, see the docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/Concepts/MessageFlow.html).

Comment: nstextfield validation not textView

Comment: @LeoDabus is the no something like this? https://github.com/jpotts18/SwiftValidator

Comment: @bogdanf is the no something like this? https://github.com/jpotts18/SwiftValidator

Comment: @Arti is my answer helping you ? If yes, please don't forget to accept my answer.

Comment: @bogdanf not sure... I asked about how to show validation errors for field. Yes, a can check in `controlTextDidChange` but how to show labels and make field red. Is there no default class or something to validate fields for cocoa osx. And what does this check box 'Validates immediately' means ?

Comment: @Arti I've updated my response to be more useful, I hope.